# Selenium - check if an image is displayed on page

Tags: image, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm creating a suite of Selenium tests for an web album application. I would like to test whether an image is actually displayed (it contains valid image data). Is such thing possible?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I faced this similar situation before where the src of the image is as expected but the image is not displayed on the page.

You can check if the image is getting displayed or not by using the JavaScriptExcecutor.

Use the following code - 
Pass the WebElement (image) -

```
 Object result = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
   "return arguments[0].complete && "+
   "typeof arguments[0].naturalWidth != \"undefined\" && "+
   "arguments[0].naturalWidth > 0", image);

    boolean loaded = false;
    if (result instanceof Boolean) {
      loaded = (Boolean) result;
      System.out.println(loaded);
    }
```

You can verify if the image has actually loaded on the webpage by doing this.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't expect anyone would post working solution after this many months. I ended up using this code to check that all images are present on the page: `var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("img"); var allOk = true; for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {allOk &= elems[i].complete && typeof elems[i].naturalWidth != "undefined" && elems[i].naturalWidth > 0;console.log(elems[i].naturalWidth);} allOk;`.

Comment: Great work! One note: our devs have a placeholder image that is 400px, and they swap that out with the lazy-loaded image when you scroll to it. So the last test, for me, is `arguments[0].naturalWidth != 400`. Check with your devs for help.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Java, selenium has a method named `eval` or so. You give it a javascript string and it gives you the result as a string. For example, you could try this (in one line):

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('get', document.getElementById('imageid').src, false);
req.send(null);
req.status==200
```

This should return "true" for status 200 or "false" for something else.

Comment: What to do if the image has no ID? The image has name and class - What to do in that case?

Comment: @RiponAlWasim you could use a querySelector. `document.querySelector('img[name="my_name"]')` or `document.querySelector('img[class="my_class"]')`

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use the [TestPlan](http://testplan.brainbrain.net/) frontend to Selenium there a few options. Once you have the URL of the image you can grab this URL and inspect the returned headers. you can also save the data to a file if you'd like to manually inspect it. Or you can write a validator in Java to take that data and check to see if it actually decodes.

If you're willing to try it out then I'll write you a sample script. I can even do a quick image validator function if you'd like.

Comment: This software looks interesting, but I'm bound to use Bromine fron-end. Our company has already spent some man-hours customizing it and dumping that work just because of the image-testing is not viable. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one liner function:

```
Boolean isImageLoaded = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].complete && typeof arguments[0].naturalWidth != \"undefined\" && arguments[0].naturalWidth > 0", imageWebElement);
```

where:

`imageWebElement` = WebElement to locate image on page

`isImageLoaded` = Result in boolean (return true if image is present, false if its not)