# Fail intern tests if any linked/referenced 404

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, intern

We are using intern + selenium webdriver + phantomJS for functional testing. Something I discovered was that invalid `<img>` references do not cause any failure of a test.

Ideally, any tests we have should be failed if the html refers to JS, CSS or images that return a 404 not found. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it:
1. save your current page
2. Browse to the is/cssimage
3. Verify that there were no load or 
4. 404 failures
5. Browse back to your original page that you saved.

This will work as long as the page you were originally on was part of a form or something that you can not directly browse back to.

Comment: Do you mean extract every JS/CSS/image reference on the current html page and browse to them directly one at a time? I had thought of that but it's a really painful way! I really hoped there's a setting for "a page that includes 404 errors should not pass".

Comment: It should be pretty fast if you do this for js and css files, but if you have a lot of images, this would be painful. You could always use a JavaScriptExcecutor. this gives a pretty good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052304/selenium-checking-image-validity