# How to verify that the image is displayed correctly on the page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to verify that the uploaded image is displayed correctly, i.e. its not distorted on the page. Is there a way to verify this.? I understand that I can verify via  contents, or by a screenshot, but that will require a manual check.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, without a making a screenshot, you cannot be sure there is a desired image displayed on a page. This is where [`needle` package](https://github.com/bfirsh/needle) can be useful.

But, if you want to avoid this, least you can do is to verify 2 things:

- there is an `img` element with appropriate `src` and other desired attributes
- it has a defined, more than 0 [`naturalWidth` value](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_naturalwidth.asp), see:

  - [Selenium - check if an image is displayed on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052304/selenium-checking-image-validity)

Comment: Does needle have the mechanism to do pixel by pixel comparison?

Comment: @Saifur it is possible by tweaking the image comparison engine: [Engines](http://needle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#engines).