# Testing Lazy-Loading image with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium

I am testing a web page which its images are loaded with lazy-loading and it needs to scroll the page.

How can i fire to load all images without scrolling to the end of the page? if the scrolling the bottom is necessary, is there any way achiving it without using execute JS?

Comment: There is a way to scroll by JS or Java Robot class. But how to test Lazy Loading of image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - check if an image is displayed on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052304/selenium-check-if-an-image-is-displayed-on-page)